# Sonarqube upload report 403

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

I have a Sonar analysis job in Jenkins which was working fine. Suddenly last week it started throwing error when uploading the report to Sonarqube server.

```
11:47:31 06:17:31.409 INFO: Analysis report generated in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/projectdirmasked/sample/.scannerwork/scanner-report
11:47:31 06:17:31.409 DEBUG: Upload report
11:47:31 06:17:31.481 DEBUG: POST 403 https://sonarqubehostnamemasked.com/api/ce/submit?projectKey=Sonar_Test&projectName=Sonar_Test | time=72ms
11:47:31 06:17:31.486 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
11:47:31 06:17:31.486 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
11:47:31 06:17:31.486 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
11:47:31 06:17:31.486 INFO: Total time: 9.877s
11:47:31 06:17:31.621 INFO: Final Memory: 39M/421M
11:47:31 06:17:31.621 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
11:47:31 06:17:31.621 ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
11:47:31 You're not authorized to run analysis. Please contact the project administrator.
```

The user belongs to the token has admin access. As well execute-analysis permission. And basically the user has assigned all the available permission in Sonarqube. So definitely it is not permission issue on the user.

All other projects using the same token in the same jenkins are able to scan successfully and upload the report.

Version: Enterprise Sonarqube 8.9.6

csharp plugin version: 8.22.0, xml plugin version: 2.2.0 (as I am scanning cs and xml files)

Any leads on this will be helpful!

Comment: Even if you are an admin, you still need explicit 'execute analysis' permission on the project. Double check that.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? We are seeing the same issue where random projects on random branches suddenly fail to upload reports? Other projects work fine, and after a while they start working agian (hours, or days)

Comment: Unfortunately no. I couldn't find anything useful related to this issue. Try creating new jenkins job with same inputs as the job which is failing and see if that helps.

Comment: Have you resolved the problem? we have the same issue. Some projects are failing with 403, while some others are working.

Comment: No, I haven't spent time on this later.

Comment: Is it a new project? There seems to be an issue in SonarQube recently where a token with Analysis permisisons does not have the Create Project right and thus fails with a 403. A User token does work. See: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/failing-to-upload-analysis-result-to-sonarqube-if-project-is-not-existing/70499

Comment: got into same issue after a year :), still don't know the root cause, you guys have any firewall solutions like AWS WAF in front of Sonarqube that is blocking the request?

Comment: I created a document to see the HTTPS request/response details made by Sonar Scanner CLI. In my case, AWS ELB is returning 403. https://karthikeayan.github.io/post/tcpdump-https/